# Providing an implemented interface in function parameter not allowed, if abstract interface is expected

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an issue right now, which lead me to a more general question regarding Java and its mechanisms of inheritance.

There is an abstract class, I need to extend, which looks like this:

```
public abstract class RichFlatMapFunction<IN, OUT> extends AbstractRichFunction implements FlatMapFunction<IN, OUT> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public abstract void flatMap(IN value, Collector<OUT> out) throws Exception;
}
```

Hence in my implementation I want (need) to override the function `flatMap()`. My own class uses `<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>, Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>` as IN and OUT parameters.

Now I am trying to override this `flatMap()` function using not the interface `Collector<OUT>` but an implementation of that interface, which looks like following:

```
public class TupleWrappingCollector<IN, K> implements Collector<IN> {...}
```

As far as I understand, I should be able to use this class instead of `Collector<OUT>`, since it fulfills this interface required by the function. Defining a `TupleWrappingCollector<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>, GenericRecord>` would result in implementing the interface with `Collector<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>`, which is exactly what the function `flatMap()` from the initial class requires, and another parameter `GenericRecord` somewhere in the class, which should not matter here.
However, I am shown an error when trying to define the method header like this:

```
public void flatMap(Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord> value, TupleWrappingCollector<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>, GenericRecord> out) {...}
```

There is no method found to be overridden, and the class requires me to specify a `flatMap()` function for `Tuple2<GR,GR>, Collector<Tuple2<GR,GR>>` and I don't see why. In my opinion, I am fulfilling the specified method header.

What am I missing here, does the `implements` disqualify the class I'm using as a valid parameter or do I have a wrong grasp on Narrowing/Widening for interfaces?

Comment: I just now realized, it's not a specialized interface but a fulfilled/implemented interface

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill the contract of `RichFlatMapFunction::flatMap`, you'll have to supply a function that can work with **any** implementation of `Collector<OUT>`.

By changing the method declaration to a specific implementation of `Collector<OUT>`, you won't be able to apply this function to a different implementation of the interface that is not a subclass of `TupleWrappingCollector<OUT, K>`.

To give you an example: Your implementation of `RichFlatMapFunction` would not be able to handle the following `Collector`, but according to the contract it's supposed to do so:

```
public class MyCollector<OUT> implements Collector<OUT> {...}
```